# How to view custom Google Analytics dashboards month-by-month

Tags: google, google-analytics

By default, the custom Google analytics dashboard widget which shows data in a timeline, shows the data on a day-by-day timeline.

I would like to see the timeline data in a month-by-month view within the dashboard.

I've tried looking for the following solutions:

(a) hacking the querystring to force a different timeline view

(b) a browser extensions which does the same

without much success.

Any other ideas/suggestions/solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sur that you are out of luck.  Normal reports in Google Analytics have a selector that lets you show that report by hour, day week, or month.  For custom dashboards, this option is not available:

[image: custom dashboard -- no by month view]

For normal reports, th query string can be "hacked" to give you a month view.   The biggest problem is that is hard to bookmark that query string.   That is because the dates in the bookmarkable query string are static, and don't change for the next month.

My solution was to create a page powered by JavaScript that calculates the dates and gives me fresh links into my Analytics in a variety of ways.   I have published the page on me website and you can use it too:  http://ostermiller.org/calc/ga.html

To use it, you need to find your Google Analytics Report ID by logging into your Analytics account and looking at the URL.  It will have an id similar to this format: `a1234567w12345678p1234567`.  Copy and paste that into the form and you will get a set of links that look like this:

[image]

To get to your custom dashboard rather than the default Google Analytics visitor overview, you will also need to find the page id for your dashboard (from a Google Analytics URL) and put it in.  I tested it with a dashboard id of `#dashboard/_vARy8q0Q5C5TChopF5_Ix`.

Unfortunately, even when you do this to add the query strings to the URL requesting the view by a different time period, Google Analytics doesn't honor it.  It appears that they just don't support this feature for custom dashboards.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look into this. If you couldn't find a way to hack CUSTOM dashboards, as I enquired, then it's probably not doable without gathering/cacheing/rerending the data via the Analytics API. I suppose that's why/how apps like dashthis.com do it.